# Lagrange interpolating polynomial what should i do when question does not specify the degree

Tags: numerical-methods

this question in my homework and this is not the first one that doesn't specify the
the degree of Lagrange interpolating polynomial
in this case, what should I do?

Comment: Hint: The number of points is all you need to determine the degree.

Comment: is the number of points equal to the polynomial degree because I use all the given data?
@MichaelBurr

Comment: Why don't you do an easy example with $2$ points and try it yourself by hand? Then you see what degree you will need. Sometimes the degree can be smaller, by the way. Take the points $(1,1);(2,2);(3,3)$ for example. 
Also please don't use pictures.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: will use MathJax 
and thx for the help <3 @DietrichBurde